# Using o-auth login on google apps domain

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid

I'm trying to create a web service for my college, which uses Google Apps for education. We have our own themed login page. I was wondering if its possible to use oauth/ openID to use our Google apps account to log in. I know when I use generic oauth, I can enter the school email address and force it to take the Google apps domain, but is there a way to redirect to it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the hd parameter in the oauth request to specify a google apps domain to login through. I believe the apps domain needs to have the option enabled and/or be a paying domain, but I am not certain about this part

Example URL

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&DOMAIN.COM&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&client_id=CLIENT_ID&type=web_server
```